# How many combinations there are in 4 letters?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

4 letters are `a b c d`

```
a
b
c
d
a+b
a+c
a+d
b+c
b+d
c+d
a+b+c
a+b+d
b+c+d
d+c+a
a+b+c+d
```

is there more combination than only 15 that i missing?

Comment: This is correct. You might include not picking anything at all as an option as well. Check out Pascal's triangle!

Comment: If you are excluding $0$ then that would be all of them. In general there are $2^n-1$ 'combinations' of $n$ letters.

Comment: I think this might be better tagged as combinatorics rather than calculus

Comment: @HenryLee done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the number of subsets of $\{a,b,c,d\}$. We can associate a subset $F$ of $S:=\{a,b,c,d\}$ to a mapping $f_F:S \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Each such mapping is a sequence of {0,1} of length $4$. There are $2^4$ such sequences because each position on the sequence can be either $0$ or $1$.  Hence the total number of subsets is $2^4=16$. Since we don't want the empty subset in this case, we get $15$.